# VPS CPU usage very high

Tags: cpu-usage, joomla

I just switched my hosting to a VPS. I will admit that server admin is something I am very very new at. Anyhow, I am getting repeated emails about my server load exceeding 100% so i clearly need to get something configured differently.

Here is my #top:
http://support.schaffner-publications.com/images/top.jpg

My VPS configuration is:

> os- CENTOS 6.5 i686 ram- 756 MB bram- 1024 MB cpu - (2) x Xeon E5645
>   24x Core software - PHP, MySQL, Apache, FFmpeg, Lame, Libogg,
>   Libvorbis, FLVtool2, Mplayer, Mencoder, AMR, kernel - 2.6.32+

I have about 15 Joomla sites all with caching turned on. Most are low traffic, although I have 1 site that gets about 10,000 pageviews per day, and one that gets about 200 pageviews per day.

How to get my load down?

Traffic stats:

```
Unknown robot (identified by 'bot*')    941,891+589 260.70 GB   12 Jul 2014 - 20:12
MSNBot  45,500+319  3.06 GB 12 Jul 2014 - 20:11
Googlebot   33,529+60   2.82 GB 12 Jul 2014 - 20:12
Unknown robot (identified by 'crawl')   11,713+65   752.50 MB   12 Jul 2014 - 20:09
Unknown robot (identified by 'robot')   10,278+24   487.78 MB   12 Jul 2014 - 19:52
Unknown robot (identified by 'spider')  6,966+13    431.20 MB   12 Jul 2014 - 20:11
Yahoo Slurp 3,986+7 261.62 MB   12 Jul 2014 - 20:10
Unknown robot (identified by '*bot')    3,691+23    246.48 MB   12 Jul 2014 - 17:54
Unknown robot (identified by empty user agent string)   1,196   68.15 MB    12 Jul 2014 - 19:54
Unknown robot (identified by hit on 'robots.txt')   0+291   245.82 KB   12 Jul 2014 - 20:09
MSNBot-media    55+68   4.03 MB 12 Jul 2014 - 19:15
Alexa (IA Archiver) 29  1.94 MB 11 Jul 2014 - 13:04
Netcraft    1   92.55 KB    10 Jul 2014 - 11:46
```

Comment: Your web traffic exceeds the capacity of your VPS to handle it. And...was that...Windows XP?!?

Comment: CENTOS 6.5, with this being a traffic thing what should i do. My awstats says my traffic from my busiest site is added to my original post

Comment: lol yes it was windows XP. im on my old netbook today that i havent gotten around to updating to 7

Comment: you have 1 zombie there, but i bet php is hanging on mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Top says it all. You are using 83% user, which is from tendesig. top -c will give more information on what is being run as well. It may be you need a larger server. You can try checking PHP error logs to see if there is anything amiss with the account. You can also check the MySQL process list to check for any long running queries. This would be "show processlist;" in MySQL.

Really, you need more cores and check that the scripts ran are optimized. There are at least 10 PHP processes competing for CPU time which is reflected in the 16 load average (average of processes waiting for CPU time). A 16 LA is not good, you want to aim for having that around 1-2 at highest.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla tends to be quite heavy on CPU. However, you can use the various cache modes to considerably improve that situation. Give a look [here](http://www.ilsistemista.net/index.php/linux-a-unix/20-joomla-cache-performance-review.html?start=3).